# MySQL Index Size

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two tables with exactly same primary keys. For example, the `school_name` columns in `table1` and `table2` have the same values (those two tables have the same number of rows).

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `school_name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    `descp` mediumtext,
    PRIMARY KEY (`school_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
    `school_name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    `address` mediumtext,
    --5 more fields here...
    PRIMARY KEY (`school_name`),
    --4 more other index...
    --E.G., KEY field_3_index (field_3)...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

Here is the index size result:

```
+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+
| database_name | table_name      | index_name         | size_in_mb |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+
| schoolsDB     | table1          | PRIMARY            |   10355.97 |
| schoolsDB     | table2          | PRIMARY            |     794.69 |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+
```

**Why does `table2`'s PRIMARY KEY index much larger than `table1`'s?**

*Looks like it is due to those extra columns and index in table2, but I don't understand the reason behind it.*

Thanks for help!

Comment: For InnoDB, the primary key basically is the complete table (e.g. InnoDB stores all the data in an index). See e.g. [Does MySQL create an extra index for primary key or uses the data itself as an “index”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57134422).

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks! How about myisam? Should the size of index be same if it is using myisam?

Comment: Yes, for MyISAM, they would have similar sizes. But is that relevant? The table data is still stored and requires space. So MyISAM has: Primary key (small), additional structure with row data (actually repeating the primary key column, since that is data too). InnoDB has: Primary key (incl. all data), NO additional stucture with row data. So the smaller primary key size itself does not make your storage requirements lower, if that is what you are after.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for the detailed explanation! Do you mind post the answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Tip: [Don't use MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706717/20860).

Comment: @BillKarwin wow that's good to know! thx!

Comment: *Here is the index size result* Have you executed OPTIMIZE TABLE before gathering this statistic?

Comment: @Akina No, I didn't. Just Googled ` OPTIMIZE TABLE` and I realized I should. Unfortunately I couldn't. Because  `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will lock the table for a while, which is under PROD environment.

Comment: Without OPTIMIZE TABLE (which compresses unused space in the table file) your statistic cannot be used for to draw some conclusions.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS`; it has more info and may help to clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use MyISAM.  Switch to InnoDB.
- InnoDB disk footprint with be 2x-3x that of MyISAM.  (This includes Data, Index, and "free" space.)
- Don't use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on InnoDB; it is a waste of time.  (There are rare exceptions.)  Yes, `OPTIMIZE` removes some of the fragmented space, but it quickly gets chewed up again as you insert/update/delete.
- MyISAM's indexes each look alike -- the key plus a pointer.
- InnoDB's `PRIMARY KEY` is really the data, sorted by the PK.  Hence its size is just the extra (non-leaf) nodes in the BTree structure.
- InnoDB's secondary keys include the key's column(s), plus the PK's column(s).
- In *most* cases, it is poor schema design to have a 1:1 pairing of tables.  Your case may be a good example of an exception -- moving a bulky column (`description`) that is rarely used out of the main table (`table2`).
- You may find that InnoDB's "compressed" is not very useful.  It saves some disk space, but does not necessarily help with speed.